# Why does "log out" affect all devices?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, logout

There is a help text when you click "log out" in the menu which warns you that it will affect your login on all devices.

Even with the warning, this violates the principle of least astonishment, at least for me, and also is usually not the action I would want to take.

My primary use case for wanting to log out is if I borrowed somebody's computer, and want to log myself out *on that device only*.  I see no reason why it should force me to authenticate anew on other devices, such as my own phone.

The fact that it also logs me out from other sites in the StackExchange network exacerbates the nuisance.  In practical terms, it means I will need to resubmit my password half a dozen times when I return to my own desktop computer.

Even if this is a conscious design decision, could it be reconsidered, at least to the point of offering a separate, alternative "on this device only" logout functionality?

Comment: Downvoters: care to comment on why you disagree?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I'm wondering here, if I forgot to log out my account in a (public) place and I could not come back very soon, it would be nice if I could do it from another device. What do you think?

Comment: Personally, I have never had that problem, whereas I have the opposite problem frequently.  At the very least, I would like to have the option to choose.  It could easily be accommodated into the warning page you get when you select "log out" -- click on either "Yes, this device only" or "Yes, everywhere" to confirm the action.

Comment: Is this a [meta-tag:discussion] or a [meta-tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm certainly open for guidance on how to decide that. I phrased this as a question and hence thought "discussion" would be more appropriate, but ultimately, I certainly hope it would result in changed behavior (in which case, is it a "bug" or a "feature request"? Haaalp).

Comment: It's a bug if the site has an error. The current behavior might not be optimal (you make a good case imho), but it is certainly not broken. Thus, a feature-request. BTW: Logging out everywhere is probably easier and more robust.

Comment: Then a [tag:feature-request] it is.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Why not suggest it sort of like facebook does it? Where they show the devices with sessions and allow you to "end" a selected session on a set device?

Comment: I agree with the feature-request. Just two options to keep it simple. _All devices_ (preselected) and _Just this device_

Comment: Wait, there's a logout button? o_O

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol StackExchange dropdown (top of the page), you will find the log out button here.

Comment: login using an incognito window, and close said window when you're done?  easier imo

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logging out on all devices has been optional for about a year and a half now:

> [image]

Comment: Moderators have the option to clear all sessions for a user as [demo-ed by Martijn here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344006/578411). Is that indeed the same as ticking the *log out on all devices*  and then clicking logout or does the moderator route invalidates more stuff?

Comment: @rene It's the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

While it may violate the principle of least astonishment, it can be considered a security best practice. Despite all precautions, proper security protocols should assume that your user session is not perfectly protected, which means that some situation could arise that allows your session to be accessed from a device that you don't have control over. This could be as simple as you using your friend's computer, and then failing to log out when you give it back to him, but the realm of session hijacking attacks is diverse and always growing, and Stack Exchange can't assume that they've protected every avenue available both now and in the future.

So, if you log out, you log out any active session, which means that any device that had access now requires your password, which is much less straight forward to gain access to.

That's the "why". In the absence of more sophisticated control over which devices have an active user session, then that's the best approach.  But I agree, providing a more granular interface for selecting certain devices is probably warranted. The default should still be to log out everything, to default to "most secure". Do keep in mind that it's a little harder to identify specific devices by browser vs., say, Facebook, which is typically accessed by an app. So the solution to this problem isn't 100% straight forward, but should be solvable.

Comment: Without looking under the hood, I can speculate that logging in creates a session cookie, and that logging out clears the same cookie.  This is how other sites operate and what brings the least astonishment.

Comment: I wouldn't be very astonished if most sites encrypted my password with unsalted md5, but I wouldn't be very happy about it (understanding that's not what you mean by "least astonishment"). You have to make usability tradeoffs to increase security. You may draw the line somewhere different than me, but I've never personally ran into this issue so I'm all for this particular security step.