# Logout of Stack Overflow on computers I no longer have access to?

Tags: support, logout

I'm signed into my account on a computer I'm no longer using, and I'd like to revoke its access to my Stack Overflow account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Both you and moderators can. You can log out of *all devices*, and moderators can reset all your sessions; you'll have to log in again on computers you do have access to.

Either log out yourself (there's a log-out link in the hamburger menu top-right) and check the *log out of all devices* box there, or I can do it for you. Would you like me to reset your sessions now?