# I forgot to log out from Stack Overflow from a public computer. What now?

Tags: discussion, logout

The owner of this account did not logout from a public computer, so a different person is posting this question on their behalf.

Comment: I do thank this person for making a sensible question when finding the account logged in rather than posting junk to get the user banned. Good on you!

Comment: Since the real user may never see this question, is it possible for a mod to forcibly log them out?

Comment: @Turnip See the top answer.

Comment: I actual meant _'Please would a moderator log this user out'_ but worded it badly.

Comment: It would be better to just ask the question, without the fluff on "teaching a lesson", etc. I don't understand who is asking this question - the original user or the other user who hijacked the original user's account. Or is it the original user who created a new throwaway account? These details don't matter much, so maybe edit the fluff out?

Comment: Why does “log out” affect all devices?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267948/7724032 for more info

Comment: "I left my moderator account logged on on a public computer, how to undelete all the posts ?"

Comment: @anatolyg It was someone other than the account owner writing this post. I've edited it to make it clear.

Answer (score 61):

Go to the hamburger menu at the top right, click 'log out' . On the log out page check the 'log out on all devices' option  and click the 'log out' button.

Or with a picture

[image: log out on all devices]

See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339071/578411

Alternatively moderators also have an option to invalidate your sessions but that follows the same code path as the "log out on all devices" . That option could be used if moderators expect your account is compromised to stop any on-going wrong doings.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

Click on the hamburger menu on the right

Then click "Logout"

[image]

Then select logout from all devices

[image]