# Let's remove the migration path from Main to Meta

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, migration

Related (not duplicates):

- [I also hate low quality / non-researched / clueless Meta questions that get migrated from Main](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354350/i-also-hate-low-quality-non-researched-clueless-meta-questions-that-get-migr)
- [Don't lock (meta) posts after a failed migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371221/dont-lock-meta-posts-after-a-failed-migration?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I saw it happen again - a new user posted an *unclear* question on the main site complaining vaguely about a bad user experience on SO. It got migrated to Meta by five apparently well-meaning but perhaps misguided 3k closevoters, and the Meta crowd promptly closed it as *Unclear What You're Asking*. This resulted in the question popping back up on Main, where it is just going to accumulate more downvotes and eventually get deleted. This creates extra trash (an unnecessary migration history as well as a closed "turd" on Meta), and creates extra work for the Meta users who have to respond and close the question that never should have been migrated in the first place.

**Let's get rid of the 3k user closevote path to migrate from Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Overflow.** Rarely have I seen a high-quality Meta question that originated on the main site - rather, the very fact that a poster didn't seem to appreciate the difference between SO and Meta.SO *itself* indicates that the poster likewise probably did not understand or take note of what makes a *good* Meta question, rather than a "Stack Overflow sux, stop downvoting me!!1!11one" rant or an *unclear* "How come I can't answer? It doesn't work".

For the rare cases in which a high quality Meta question *does* appear on the main site (e.g. due to sheer luck, or a heavily sleep-deprived but experienced user), a moderator flag can be raised for migration to Meta.

Comment: I don't think leaving such posts on main to collect downvotes is any nicer... Maybe closure on meta should not reject migration from main instead?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov well, I linked to a feature request in which that very thing was requested, and now we are here in 2019 and nothing has changed. This change (remove the migration path) may be *easier* to implement than coding in a special-case behavior for certain migrations.

Comment: Moderators don't have enough work to do so dealing with requests to evaluate and move posts to meta should be added to their tasks?

Comment: I've seen plenty of high-quality questions originally from the main site.

Comment: Some stats: In the past 90 days, 52 posts were migrated from SO to Meta, and 67% of those ended up rejected. We also had 18 migrations from Meta.SE to Meta (33% rejected) and [one surprise migration from Crypto.SE (rejected)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377320/using-webcrypto-to-generate-ecdh-key-from-pbkdf2) (that post was [misdirected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565921/using-webcrypto-to-generate-ecdh-key-from-pbkdf2)).

Comment: So the stats don't look that great. Still, Meta closes a lot of posts *generally*. I don't think that the stats are the only thing to look at here. For example, [this post was migrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379217/i-forgot-to-log-out-from-stack-overflow-from-a-public-computer-what-now), received well here, and was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You lost me there. What am I intended to learn from those stats? Is it that this is a minor problem because it's only a small number of questions in three months time?

Comment: @Gimby: I'm just sharing the stats. What you learn from them is your own, I didn't intend to infer anything from them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough, then I don't feel too stupid for not catching your drift, there was none to catch :)

Answer (score 11):

You're going to have to sell this to me.

Here's the scope of Meta as I understand it:

- A place to discuss the direction and policies of the site.
- A place to ask questions about how to use the site and its functionality.
- A place to report bugs and problems with using the site.
- A place to garner constructive criticism or feedback of questions (or answers) on the site.
- A place to ask constructive questions about moderation actions taken against posts on the site.

Out of that, "high-quality" becomes subjective at *best*.  You can have a good and constructive discussion come from someone who had their question closed and they disagree with it, and you could not.  But that doesn't instantly make the post "high-quality".

We deal with rants just fine here - close them, delete them, move on with our lives.  Migrating that off of the main site means that, at a minimum, it's not going to get picked up by a search engine crawler.

If you're only ever going to look for high-quality Meta questions, you're going to be looking high and low.  When you *do* find them, let me know where they're hiding - I'd just sooner move to where they are than have them come to me.

Comment: High quality is not really subjective when talking about migrated questions like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379583/how-to-extract-code-snippet-from-stackoverflow-posts) [1/2]

Comment: I'm not proposing that there be no way to migrate from Main to Meta. I'm saying that this should be done by moderators (who should know enough to not migrate crap), not random users who just happen to have enough rep to closevote.

Comment: [2/2] But I agree with Makoto: The majority of migrated posts that I see are at least ok. Maybe not high quality but at the average quality level meta has anyway.

Comment: @BDL:  This sounds like a simpler problem - have a moderator [talk to the people who elected to migrate this question over here in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54357837/revisions).  How *often* would this occur that it requires us to remove the migration path?

Comment: @RobertColumbia:  What happens to people who migrate crap these days, anyway?  We usually let the moderators deal with them and that becomes a non-factor.  The site then receiving the crap (as it were) then has a talk about whether or not they want to *keep* receiving it.  As where we stand today I don't see any compelling reason to believe that we're inundated with *migration* crap, so I don't see a benefit to giving more work for moderators in this context.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the few cases where **migration actually makes sense**. Pretty much everyone on SO that has close votes can judge when a question on main is actually a meta post. And I don't even mind the bad ones that much in this case: they're gonna get dealt with _real quick_ on Meta, faster even than they would on main most likely.

Comment: Although, having said that...is that actually a question about _scraping_ SO, and therefore (nominally) on-topic for main?

Comment: Yeah @JoshCaswell, at first glance it reads like someone wants to scrape the site.  Okay, that's probably on topic for SO since site scraping _is a thing_, but it's not exactly a good question, either.  It'd have been fine on main and the migration action was wholly inappropriate.  I see opportunity for a misunderstanding, but barely.

Comment: Yep, it needs to be closed one way or the other.